# Tensorflow downloaded but not installed on ubuntu server

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using pip install tensorflow to install in environment. Package is downloaded but not installed. When I use tensorflow, it shows no module name tensoflow.

[image]

Tensorflow is downloaded but not installed.

**Edit**

When running `import tensorflow`:

> (bot_venv):~/Chatbot/ChatBot/chatbot$ python
> -c "import tensorflow" Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'tensorflow'

**Edit 2**

Running `pip list` (it's a big list and tensorflow is not in it). When I used `requirements.txt` to insatll packages, it showed packages are dowloading but nothing installed. I used `pip install p_name` one by one for all packages. Worked for all except `tensorflow`.

```
absl-py              0.9.0
aioredis             1.3.1
amqp                 2.6.1
asgiref              3.2.7
astor                0.8.1
async-timeout        3.0.1
attrs                19.3.0
autobahn             20.4.3
Automat              20.2.0
billiard             3.5.0.5
cachetools           4.0.0
certifi              2019.11.28
cffi                 1.14.0
channels             2.4.0
channels-redis       2.4.1
chardet              3.0.4
colorama             0.4.3
configparser         4.0.2
constantly           15.1.0
contextvars          2.4
crayons              0.3.0
cryptography         2.9.2
daphne               2.5.0
Django               2.2.4
django-paypal        1.0.0
djangorestframework  3.11.0
gast                 0.2.2
google-auth          1.11.0
google-auth-oauthlib 0.4.1
google-pasta         0.1.8
googletrans          3.0.0
grpcio               1.26.0
h11                  0.9.0
h2                   3.2.0
h5py                 2.10.0
hiredis              1.0.1
hpack                3.0.0
hstspreload          2020.6.16
httpcore             0.9.1
httpx                0.13.3
hyperframe           5.2.0
hyperlink            19.0.0
idna                 2.8
immutables           0.14
importlib-metadata   1.7.0
incremental          17.5.0
jsonfield            2.0.2
Keras                2.4.3
Keras-Applications   1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing  1.1.0
kombu                4.6.11
Markdown             3.1.1
msgpack              0.6.2
mysqlclient          1.4.6
nltk                 3.4.5
numpy                1.18.1
oauthlib             3.1.0
opt-einsum           3.1.0
Pillow               7.1.2
pip                  20.2.3
pkg-resources        0.0.0
protobuf             3.11.2
pyasn1               0.4.8
pyasn1-modules       0.2.8
pycparser            2.20
PyHamcrest           2.0.2
pyOpenSSL            19.1.0
pytz                 2020.1
PyYAML               5.3
redis                3.3.11
requests             2.22.0
requests-oauthlib    1.3.0
rfc3986              1.4.0
rsa                  4.0
scipy                1.4.1
selenium             3.141.0
service-identity     18.1.0
setuptools           50.3.0
six                  1.14.0
sniffio              1.1.0
sqlparse             0.3.1
tensorboard          2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator 2.1.0
termcolor            1.1.0
Twisted              20.3.0
txaio                20.4.1
urllib3              1.25.7
vine                 1.3.0
webdriver-manager    2.3.0
Werkzeug             0.16.0
wheel                0.35.1
wrapt                1.11.2
zipp                 3.1.0
zope.interface       5.1.0
```

Comment: try to run python -c "import tensorflow" and show us the output

Comment: @KetZoomer, I have added the output. Can you suggest something.

Comment: run `pip list` and show us the output

Comment: @KetZoomer, Question updated. Please check if you have time.

Comment: show full log - u might have installed it for another environment. Please add `which python`, `which pip`. Also, try to do it inside a virtualenv: run the following - `virtualenv venv; . venv/bin/activate; pip install tensorflow; python -c "import tensorflow"; echo $?`

Comment: Please don't post images of text; see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: The "Killed" message looks like you ran out of memory.

Comment: I have checked. environment is activate. Python 3.6, pip 20, ubuntu 18. Now I am going to remove everything and going to start everything from scratch. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @tripleee I checked, there is no space issue.

Comment: "Space" sounds like you checked disk space, but RAM is a completely separate resource. It is of course possible that you killed the install yourself; we can only look at what's visible in your question.

Comment: I used requirements.txt file install packages. Everything installed except tensorflow. I have installed this .txt earlier on another server without any issue. I don't know what I am doing wrong this time.

Comment: pip and python might be referring to python2, and pip3 and python3 might me referring to python3

Comment: what is the output of python --version and python3 --version

Comment: and try pip3 install tensorflow, pip3 list, and python3 -c "import tensorflow"

Comment: I got the solution. This worked. "pip install tensorflow --no-cache-dir" thanks for your time. @KetZoomer